# I need an idea for recovering my data

Tags: usb-on-the-go, broken-screen, moto-x, motorola

after I tried for 4 hours, I really need your help. Let me tell you my story:
I dropped Moto X 2nd Gen (running Android 6.0) some days ago, the screen is shattered and only shows some kind of green mud. The only 2 activitys I can recognize trough the screen are the android animations when scrolling or switching between and (for sure) if the screen is turned on or off. ADB is turned off and there is no way to enable it. I attached a keyboard via USB-OTG and am able to unlock the phone, but when I connect it to my pc, I can't access my data because the phone is in Charge-only mode (THANKS for making this default, Android! -.-). So my only hope is the keyboard. I borrowed the exact same phone from a friend, attached the keyboard and wrote down the keys I need to press to enable Wifi. The reason for that is my Chromecast, as soon as I mirrored my display, I can use my mouse to upload my data from the phone to my cloud. So I repeated the keys on the broken phone, and after MANY attempts I finally got wifi turned on using the keyboard. But now I keep struggling at the next step, starting the screen mirroring. My Keys are:

> Type 'Settings' on the home screen
>   4 times down, then enter to select
>   4 times down again, to the 'display' settings, enter
>   All the way down, hit enter to get to screen mirroring
>   Wait a moment so it can find devices
>   Go all the way down again and hit enter to select my chromecast

These steps work just fine on the other phone, but when I use it on the broken one, I always get stuck in a big block of text which is scrollable. I have no idea what it is, and the only way to get rid of it is rebooting.

Any ideas how to get that damn screen mirrored? My goal is SO close!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would also be interesting why the first line is gone...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vysor chrome app for screen mirroring, if your device's debugging mode is enabled.
Things you needed is a USB cable attached to PC with chrome installed.

or you can try any of the below,

1. EaseUS Android data recovery software.
2. MHL to female HDMI adapter, to connect to TV

Comment: Debugging is disabled and the phone doesn't support MHL. Does EaseUS have any requirements?